# How do i get one item per row in a timevis gantt chart?

Tags: r

I am working with the timevis library in R. I want a gannt diagram with one line per item. The following example will stack items after another if there is room. Is there a way to force the diagram to have as many rows as there are items?

```
library(timevis)

data <- data.frame(
id      = 1:4,
content = c("Item one"  , "Item two"  ,"Ranged item", "Item four"),
start   = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11", "2016-01-20", "2016-02-14"),
end     = c(NA          ,           NA, "2016-02-04", NA)
)

timevis(data)
```

This gives the following output from timevis:

[image: Output]

But I want each of the items on a separate line

[image]

I am aware of other packages than timevis, but I would prefer using timvis as the interactivity is very usefull for what I am trying to vizualise.

Comment: Look here for a full list of options: http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Configuration_Options

Comment: Providing a `subGroup` within your data might do the trick. See here: http://visjs.org/docs/timeline/#Data_Format

Answer (score 0):

From the examples, slightly modified:

```
timevis(data = data.frame(
  start = c(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+1, Sys.Date() + 2, Sys.Date() + 3),
  content = c("one", "two", "three", "four"),
  group = c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
  groups = data.frame(id = 1:4, content = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4"))
)
```

This should be a good starting point.

[image]

Comment: I suppose forcing each item into its own group could work, but I am planning on using the group function to, well, group items. Maybe I could use subgroups in addition? I was hoping there was some option to force each item on one row.

Answer (score 0):

You need the option: stack = TRUE for this, this puts them on different lines inside a group, example final call below

tv <<- timevis(main,group, showZoom =  FALSE,options = list(
  editable = TRUE,stack = TRUE, showCurrentTime = FALSE,multiselect = TRUE,align = "center"))